# Change UIView width in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I'm working on the Swift project now and stuck on how to change my UIView's width in code.

In my storyboard, I have gray-colored UIView.

[image: Gray view on right side of landscape device]

I set its width, in the inspector, as

> equals: 160

However, I don't want to give an exact number for my UI, so I made `@IBOutlet` to it and tried to set the value as 0.2 * parent view's width. But when I build I cannot see the width changes...

```
@IBOutlet weak var parentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var grayArea: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    grayArea.frame.size.width = parentView.frame.size.height * 0.2
}
```

I searched similar questions on Stack Overflow but none of them worked for my code. Could anyone please point me what I'm doing wrong in here?

Comment: Did you add a _constraint_ in the inspector? That could be why you can't change it via code. But anyway, you _should_ use constraints, just not a constant width constraint.

Comment: Thank you so much Sweeper. 
I used constraints instead of constant width and worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Sweeper said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67067791/change-uiviews-width-in-swift5/67067857#comment118548348_67067791), you won't be able to change the frame of views that have constraints added. Instead, if you want the width to always equal 0.2 of the parent, you should just use a proportional constraint.

1. Right-click on the gray view, and hold
2. Drag to the parent view, then release
3. Choose <kbd>Equal Widths</kbd>
4. In the attributes inspector, select the constraint that you just added
5. Click <kbd>Edit</kbd>
6. Enter `0.2` for the "Multiplier"
7. Done!

[image: GIF of the above steps]